# Odd with the main() function in C

Tags: c, parameters, parameter-passing, program-entry-point

When I attempt to pass parameters into the main() function in C, I could always only get 1 parameter(and the argc is always 1, the name of the program). My program is well compiled in gcc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "chkin.h"
#include "sort.h"
#include "display.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(1 == chkin(argc, argv))
        return 0;

    if(strcmp("sort", argv[1]));
        sort(argc, argv);

    if(strcmp("display", argv[1]));
        display(argc, argv);

    return 0;
}
```

and my running commad is: ./program sort tfile.txt.
What would be the problem?

Comment: Your code doesn't show the problem.  What happens if you add: `for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) puts(argv[i]);` before the call to `chkin()`?  If you don't see three lines of output, you've got problems in your shell.  If you do see three lines of output ("`./program`", "`sort`", "`tfile.txt`"), then we need to see what you're doing in `chkin()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

gdb (based on your comment to @Jack) will only read the first argument 'program'.
If you want to run the program via gdb you must try :

```
gdb ./program
(gdb) r sort tfile.txt
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Can you also show code for chkin and display? 
Most likely, problem lies there.

Alternatively, you can attach your program to gdb and then say "br main; r sort file.txt; p argv; p argc"

Comment: When I run my program directly, everything goes will(and argc is 3), however, when I use gdb(p argc), the result is 1. What's the problem?